# Open new Window in an MVVM WPF App

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a WPF MVVM app that using PRISM. I have a toolbar UserControl which is bind to the ViewModel so it can invoke the commands on the ViewModels as shown below:

```
 <ToolBar Height="auto">
        <Button Content="New"/>
        <Button Content="Edit" Command="{Binding Path=EditCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem}"  />
        <Button Content="Refresh"/>
        <Button Content="Delete"/>
        <Button Content="Close"/>
    </ToolBar>
```

The EditCommand invoke the following method in the ViewModel:

```
 private void Edit(UserViewModel userViewModel)
        {
            // load the edit page 



        }
```

In the Edit method I need to replace the current window with the edit window. How can I do that? I do not want to create or use UI elements in the Edit method because it goes against the MVVM model architecture.

Comment: Since you are already using PRISM, are you familiar with Interaction Requests? In MVVM you raise the request whenever you want a new dialog(usercontrol,window)

Comment: You can read more about InteractionRequests over here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405494%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx#sec12

Answer (score -1):

Create a `DataTemplate` for the current window that you have and create triggers to change the `Template` of the window to the `Edit` template.

Sample trigger

```
<Style TargetType="Window">
  <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsInEditMode}" Value="True">
       <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource EditModeTemplate}">
      </DataTrigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Sample data template, assuming you just want a `TextBox`

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="EditModeTemplate">
  <TextBox/>
</DataTemplate>
```

In your `Edit` method, you can just set the a boolean property to true or false whether to show an edit window or not.

```
public void Edit(UserViewModel viewModel)
{
  IsInEditMode = true;
}
```

Comment: Your answer has absolutely nothing to do with the question that is being asked.

Comment: You are asking how to replace current window with edit window. Isn't that your question? Or you want to open a dialog in your `Edit` method? Because your title and your question in the description is contradicting.